# A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released - Error

Tags: android, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm not sure why I am getting this error, 2 out of 5 times I set the wallpaper using the emulator, I get the error -
 "A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks."

When I set the wallpaper using my phone, it works perfectly without fault. Why does it crash when I use I use the emulator?

Here's my code:

```
public class SetWallpaperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String image_url;
URL mImageUrl;
String myFileUrl1;
Bitmap bmImg = null;

public SetWallpaperAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Setting Wallpaper...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        mImageUrl = new URL(args[0]);
        // myFileUrl1 = args[0];

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mImageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();


        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bmImag = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);





    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
    try {
        wpm.setBitmap(bmImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pDialog.dismiss();

}

}
```

LOG Cat:

```
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:528)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:836)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at com.google.ads.internal.f.b(SourceFile:490)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at com.google.ads.internal.f.run(SourceFile:460)
11-09 15:09:11.726: E/StrictMode(1632):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emulators have StrictMode on by default, on real devices it can be turned on in code via:

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog()
                                .penaltyDeath().build());
```

The crash you're getting here says you need to manually close opened web resources so they could free the memory, see this example from [Android docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
```