# inflater.inflate within onCreateView of fragment is throwing Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following lines within a `Fragment` are throwing an exception for which I am unable to find the root cause.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_pane, container, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();

    // set width height
    params.height = (getArguments().getInt(HEIGHT));
    params.width = (getArguments().getInt(WIDTH));

    fragmentHeight = (getArguments().getInt(HEIGHT));
    fragmentWidth = (getArguments().getInt(WIDTH));

    // substitute parameters for left,top, right, bottom, (All 4 not necessary)
    params.setMargins((getArguments().getInt(LEFT_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(TOP_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(RIGHT_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN)));

    youTubePlayerNecessary = getArguments().getBoolean(REQUIRE_YOUTUBE);
    rotate = getArguments().getBoolean(REQUIRE_ROTATION);
    muteAudio = getArguments().getBoolean(MUTE_AUDIO);

    rootView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return rootView;
}
```

Exception:

```
11-02 11:36:04.966 3440-3452/com.blynq.app.multipaneplayer E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:127)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startChromiumLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:16107)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.ensureChromiumStartedLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:333)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startYourEngines(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:427)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:162)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:554)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:489)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:472)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:459)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at com.blynq.app.fragments.PlayerPane.onCreateView(PlayerPane.java:181)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

I am currently running app in debug mode to check all possible memory leaks.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
    }
```

All tags in manifest file are properly closed too. I am unable to figure out which resource was left open without being handled. How do I resolve this ?

P.S. I have referred to [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544021/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-see-java-io) before asking the question, which is a very generic question offering no new necessary insight for me. This question is very specific to the details mentioned above, here I am seeking help to find which resource is causing the leak..

Comment: Check your manifest file and confirm if all your tags are properly closed, if you are using okHttp, then it's a known bug for older version. Update it to a newer version

Comment: Yes, all tags in manifest file are properly closed. I am not using okHttp within my project, using `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1` for http communications

Comment: post complete fragment_player_pane and oncreateview method

Comment: check whether your <activity> tag in manifest is enclosed within <application> tag .

Comment: @Umar - Added more detail, please check

Comment: what are you trying to achieve first getting layour params from rootview then adding the same to same rootview object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544021/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-see-java-io)

Comment: @jay Hi, did you figure out what causes the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody raised an issue for this here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226751

I've been having the same issue, and it looks like it's a bug in API < 25. Try your program in an emulator with API 25 and see if it works. If it works there, then it is most likely the same problem and you are out of luck until is able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog()
                                .penaltyDeath().build());
```

For more Information Follow this Url 
[Error Solve Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877631/a-resource-was-acquired-at-attached-stack-trace-but-never-released-error)

Comment: That's not fixing the issue, only hiding the violation.